# Spring unresolvable circular reference Quartz

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Autowired
private Scheduler scheduler;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SchedulingApplication.class, args);
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        this.scheduler.start();
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to start scheduler");
    }
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource) {
    SchedulerFactoryBean bean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    bean.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    bean.setAutoStartup(true);
    bean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("/config/quartz.properties"));

    AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

    bean.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

    return bean;
}
```

Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactoryBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference??

Works with spring boot 1.2.3, doesn't work with latest 1.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SchedulerFactoryBean is used to create instances of Scheduler.
In your configuration Spring tries to inject a Scheduler before it executes the @Bean methods, so before your SchedulerFactoryBean is created.
Thats why you get the Exception.
If you split it up, one configuration with the SchedulerFactoryBean and another using the Scheduler it should work.